# How do I paste values from a column in Google sheets to another column using VBA?

Tags: vba, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a sheet where column B2:B25 is populated using a formula. This column is supposed to be DateType but since it comes from concatenation, it is a string.
I want the column C:C25 to be populated with the values in B2:B25 as DateType.

Since I need to do this on a Google sheet, how do I execute the VBA script on Google sheet? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any scripts for this. In cell C2, enter

```
=arrayformula(datevalue(B2:B25))
```

and this will convert the strings in column B into corresponding date values. You will also need to format column C as dates: select it and pick "Format > Number > Date" from the menu.

---

Aside: there is no VBA in Google Sheets. Its scripting language is based on JavaScript, and is called [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros).